# nltk program is too slow

Tags: python, nltk

I have (partly) developed a program with Python that uses NLTK and other libraries to process an entire book. Now, the problem is that the program looks up the etymology of EACH word in the book on an online dictionary and therefore takes too much time to process everything.

Does someone know how I can solve this? Or if there's a faster way of looking up etymology (not definition) of a word instead of scrapping a web?

Comment: Use a dictionary on your computer.

Comment: This is unanswerable as it stands. This type of question may be better suited for a forum. If you have specific code questions, SO is where to post it. Just so you don't leave empty handed, consider caching some words so you don't have to look up every single word.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what it is you wish to do, but it sounds as though you are having problems with iterating over a large data set. In that case, and in any case you wish to print (or do anything actually) with a large data set's objects, you should probably use [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which are runtime iterators which iterate over the iterable objects dynamically and are therefore suited to the task of going over very large data sets. What you could do might be something like this:

```
def generator(l):
    for i in l:
        yield i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    very_large_list = [1,2,3]
    for i in generator(very_large_list):    # Iterate over the list dynamically without storing in memory
        print i
```